# Why pandoc keeps span and div tags when converting html to markdown?

Tags: html, markdown, pandoc

I'm a pandoc newbie, so I must be missing something obvious.
I'm trying to convert MS Word generated HTML file to markdown.
Here is a test html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="Section1">
    <p class="Question"><span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Today</span> <span style=
    "FONT-SIZE: 10pt">is</span> <span lang="HR" style=
    "FONT-SIZE: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: HR">a</span><span style=
    "FONT-SIZE: 10pt">nice</span> <span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt">day</span> 
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and I try to convert it with:

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown test.html -o test.md
```

I was expecting "Today is a nice day", but got:

```
<div class="Section1">

<span style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Today</span> <span
style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt">is</span> <span lang="HR"
style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt; mso-ansi-language: HR">a</span><span
style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt">nice</span> <span
style="FONT-SIZE: 10pt">day</span>

</div>
```

Why was the div kept?
Why were the spans kept?

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for asking this, because I found this super-annoying, too, and I probably would've gone on and stripped out the `<span>`s and `<div>`s by some other horrible means!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to turn off some [extensions](http://pandoc.org/README.html#raw-html). Either on the HTML input side:

```
$ pandoc -f html-native_divs-native_spans -t markdown test.html -o test.md
```

Or on the markdown output side:

```
$ pandoc -f html -t markdown-raw_html-native_divs-native_spans-fenced_divs-bracketed_spans test.html -o test.md
```